# Mojo (Mac) using wrong python lib

Tags: python, modular, mojolang

As most Mac users, I have two separate versions of python on my machine: The one installed by Apple (version 3.9 in `/usr/bin`) and one installed via Homebrew (version 3.11 in `/opt/homebrew/bin`).

I've put the latter first in path and, sure enough,

```bash
which python3
```

prints

> /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

and

```bash
python3 --version
```

prints

> Python 3.11.6

but Mojo seems to use the other version, as packages installed via `pip3` are not accessible.

The following `sys_path.`

```py
from python import Python
 
def main():
 
    let sys = Python.import_module("sys")
    print(sys.prefix)
```

prints

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9

How do I make Mojo use the correct python lib?

Comment: How are you running Mojo? What does the `PATH` look like inside it?

Comment: @tripleee from the terminal. The `PATH` looks exactly like it is supposed to, everything starting with `opt/homebrew/` comes first. And, as mentioned above, calling `python3 --version` gives me the right one inside that terminal.

Comment: If you are genuinely missing the slash before `opt/` then that's the problem right there.

Comment: No, that slash is there, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found not one but two possible solutions:

1. Manually edit `~/.modular/modular.cfg`, in group `mojo` find `python_lib` and set it to the path to the python lib installed with homebrew. In my case I've had to change

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3
```

to

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/libpython3.11.dylib
```

2. `EXPORT`ing `MOJO_PYTHON_LIBRARY` with the correct path will override the config setting for the current session. I've put

```
export MOJO_PYTHON_LIBRARY="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/libpython3.11.dylib"
```

in my `~/.zshrc`. Don't forget to `source` or restart the terminal when using the rc file.

The second option comes in handy, if you want to test against different versions of the python lib.